# python sax parsing big float numbers

Tags: python, python-2.6

Ok here's the story. I save big float numbers in an xml file. for example 0.016780745002189634. Numbers are saved correctly in file but when i parse the xml and i read them , some of them , (i pressume the largest ones) sax breaks them into two different numbers. Like: 0.016780 and 745002189634 .
I am using utf-8 encoding if it has something to do, tried also iso same problem with different results thought.
Thanks in advance

```
import xml.sax
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator
from xml.sax.xmlreader import AttributesNSImpl


floattosave = 0.016780745002189634
def xmlindex():
    logger = XMLGenerator(open('.\\a.xml','w'), 'utf-8')
    logger.startDocument()
    attrs = AttributesNSImpl({}, {})
    logger.startElementNS((None,'Articles'), 'Articles', attrs)
    attr_vals = {
        (None, 'id'): str(1)
        }
    attr_qnames = {
        (None, 'id'): 'id'
        }
    attrs = AttributesNSImpl(attr_vals, attr_qnames)
    logger.startElementNS((None, 'Article'), u'Article', attrs)
    attr_vals1 = {
    (None, 'word'): 'lalala'
    }
    attr_qnames1 = {
    (None, 'word'): 'word'}
    attrs1 = AttributesNSImpl(attr_vals1, attr_qnames1)
    logger.startElementNS((None, 'Lemma'), 'Lemma', attrs1)
    logger.characters(repr(floattosave))
    logger.endElementNS((None, 'Lemma'), 'Lemma')
    logger.endElementNS((None, 'Article'), 'Article')
    logger.endElementNS((None, 'Articles'), 'Articles')
    logger.endDocument()



class myhandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
        def __init__(self):
            xml.sax.ContentHandler.__init__(self)
            self.w = 0
            self.child = 0
        def startElement(self,name,attrs):
            if name == 'Article':
                self.child = 1
            if name == 'Lemma':
                self.child = 2
        def characters(self, content):
            if self.child == 2:
                print content
                a = float(content)
                print a
xmlindex()
xml.sax.parse(open('.\\a.xml'),myhandler())
```

Hmm i doing something like that but for many more elements . This is one is working good , i guess somewhere else is the problem . I ll look into it. You helped a lot tkx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with whether the text represents floating-point numbers or not -- XML parsers don't care what the consumer thinks the text means.

Your problem is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.characters).

> ContentHandler.characters(content)
>
> ```
> Receive notification of character data.
> ```
>
> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character data.
>   **SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, or they may split it into several chunks;** however, all of the
>   characters in any single event must come from the same external entity
>   so that the Locator provides useful information.

You are responsible for gluing the chunks together. In your `startElement` handler, initialise a storage. In your `characters` handler, add the incoming chunk to your storage. In your `endElement` handler, do something with your storage.